# delicious bookmarks - urls frequently bookmarked

Tags: data-mining, delicious-api

I haven't found any pre-made scripts that would help me analyze my delicious bookmarks. I want to know if there are any websites that I tend to frequently bookmark. I know I can export my bookmarks and can go from there. Has anyone done this? How have you gone about it?

On a side note - are there any RSS readers that do something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd suggest the easiest thing to do would be to export them all as XML (using the AJAX API) or HTML, then parse them all into an array, iterate through them and extract the domains and then sort the list and do value counting so you end up with a hash like {"example.org" => 1, "cnn.com", 50} etc. Then sort them so you can see your top ten.

How you do that would depend on which programming language and libraries you prefer to use. I'd probably use Nokogiri and Ruby. Basically, download the data using the API, parse it using the XML parsing library for your preferred programming language, use a URI library to extract the host part of the URI (or use a regular expression) and then just jiggle the array around until it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the [Export / Download Your Delicious Bookmarks](https://secure.delicious.com/settings/bookmarks/export) page for further analysis?